# BitBucket cannot push, "fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly"

Tags: git, http, ssh, repository, bitbucket

When trying to push to my new BitBucket repository, I keep getting this error:

```
Counting objects: 28, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (28/28), done.
Writing objects: 100% (28/28), 10.82 MiB | 7.29 MiB/s, done.
Total 28 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSL read: error:140943FC:SSL
routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad record mac, errno 0
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I get the same error in SourceTree as well.  I tried messing with the config file to increase buffer size as shown below:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

I would like to just push from the command prompt.  I should also note that some folders were able to push to repository but others were not.

Wondering what to do.  I noticed there is another post about this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240815/git-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly), but I wanted to state my case where I have tried all of these and to no avail.

Comment: Did you resolve this at all @Alec-Brenton?

Comment: I did.  But with time.  There was no fix.  It seemed to work after a few days. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want to use SSH as I am on Windows 10 without a server to use SSH from

You still could [push through ssh](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html) though: [git for windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) has openssh included in its distro. Maybe your server does not have the right to use ssh for outbound transaction? I know I cannot use ssh on any server in my company.

Check if the issue persists, as there was a [recent incident report for Atlassian Bitbucket](http://status.bitbucket.org/incidents/m5wvxzy2yhp4) affecting Git via HTTPS.
That "bad record mac" ssl error is about "[Message Authentication Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code)", and suggests an [upgrade of ssl library on the server side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6275581/6309) (as part of the incident resolution).
Make sure to use the latest git for Widows 2.8.3.

Comment: I really do appreciate your response.  Well thought out and detailed.  I've yet to try SSH as i am binded by my PC settings.  With that, I was looking for a direct answer for using git.  So thank you very much for your answer and I will look into it further, I just need a definite answer for BitBucket's git

Answer (score 0):

I was doing a `git-tf` migration when I got this issue, and being primarily a TFS user I didn't really know where to start with this one.

The quick fix that allowed me to perform the sync/check-in was to temporarily turn off "*This is a private repository*" from within the BitBucket project settings.

Comment: PS: The commit was a success, but I've noticed that it seems to be related to a different Bit Bucket account than the one I was logged in with and assumed it was using. Perhaps the deeper issue for me was that I was trying to commit using an account that didn't have the correct privileges, some how ...